# (Java) get String value after second to the last forward slash and last forward slash

Tags: java, string

I need to get a certain string value after a slash "/" but I am having trouble because the format value of the string is not always the same.

The value of string are the ff:

```
String raw = "Announcements/announcement_id)";
```

All I need here is the **announcement_id** which can be obtain with the use of `lastIndexOf("/")+1` but this is not always the format of the string it could be also like this.

```
String raw = "Announcements/announcement_id/Comments/comment_id)";
```

Here all I need are both **announcement_id** and **comment_id**.

For the last part string value could be also like this.

```
String raw = "Announcements/announcement_id/Comments/comment_id/Replies/reply_id)";
```

Here all I need are both **comment_id** and **reply_id**.

How do I get this right like using if else statement.

```
if(has only one slash)
   use lastIndexOf("/")+1 to get the id

else if (has three or more slashes)
   get the value after second to the last forward slash and last forward slash
```

Comment: use String.split("/") and check the length of the returned array

Comment: Why no `announcement_id` in last example? I think a regex would work then

Comment: @XtremeBaumer I do not need announcement_id as of now

Comment: In that case, Stultuske's idea is what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String s = "Announcements/announcement_id/Comments/comment_id/Replies/reply_id";
String[] h = s.split("\\/");
switch (h.length) {
case 2:
    System.out.println(h[1]);
    break;
case 4:
    System.out.println(h[1] + " " + h[3]);
    break;
case 6:
    System.out.println(h[3] + " " + h[5]);
    break;
default:
    break;

}
```

This code also provides a way on how to continue after the split, as well as access the elements you need

Comment: Wow! Thanks you make it more simple. I just want to ask why \\/ and not just / ?

Comment: `String#split()` works with a regular expression. `\\` the double backslash escapes the `/` forward slash and makes sure that you don't get some random results

Comment: So, what's the special meaning of `/` in a regexp? Can you point to the documentation of it in https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/regex/Pattern.html ?

Comment: In Java regex, you don't need to escape `/` (unlike in most other languages/tools where you need to do as default regex delimiter is `/` which you can even change to avoid escaping `/` there as well) and can simply split it like this `s.split("/");`

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi so split("\\/") and split("/") is always the same?

Comment: Okay I check it now and the IDE says that regex cause a redundancy which means split("\\/") and split("/") is always the same.

Comment: My comment was based on the regex php flavor. [This example](https://regex101.com/r/boBgC6/1) shows what I was refering to

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi that might be true for Java, but PHP and JavaScript, can't parse an unescaped forward slash

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: Yes in PHP you need to, because the default delimiter is `/` which you can easily change to something like `~` and in that case you don't have to escape `/` [Check this](https://regex101.com/r/boBgC6/2) Also, this post is only in context with Java.

Comment: It can be changed for PHP, but not for JavaScript. Also an answer should be complete and hint to possible mistakes in case one would assume that its the same in every case. I just added it, so OP would know about escaping etc

Comment: @XtremeBaumer: If you wanted to make your answer complete, you should've added all that information in your post. But instead, you reacted only after I posted that in my comment. Also, as this post is tagged for Java, your answer should have only used `/` instead of `\/`. Besides, if you cared for other languages, then you should have clearly mentioned this in your post, as to how it needs to be done in other languages. Also, just so you know, even in JavaScript, you can use regex object just like Java `new RegExp ("/")` where you don't have to deal with unnecessary escaping `/`

Answer (score 4):

You can use this regex, which allows optional parts in string and appropriately captures `announcement_id`, `comment_id` and `reply_id`

```
(?:Announcements/([^/]*))(?:/Comments/([^/]*))?(?:/Replies/([^/]*))?\)
```

Each of which you can access by group1, group2 or group3 respectively.

And as each part is made optional, hence it allows you to optionally have reply_id without having commend_id and as per your samples, I have made announcement_id as mandatory even which you can make it optional.

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Eh2Uaw/1)**

Check out this sample Java code,

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("Announcements/announcement_id)",
        "Announcements/announcement_id/Comments/commend_id)",
        "Announcements/announcement_id/Comments/comment_id/Replies/reply_id)");

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:Announcements/([^/]*))(?:/Comments/([^/]*))?(?:/Replies/([^/]*))?\\)");

list.forEach(x -> {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(x);
    if (m.matches()) {
        System.out.println("For string '" + x + "' --> announcement_id: " + m.group(1) + ", commend_id: "
                + m.group(2) + ", reply_id: " + m.group(3));
    }
});
```

Which prints the data appropriately as found,

```
For string 'Announcements/announcement_id)' --> announcement_id: announcement_id, commend_id: null, reply_id: null
For string 'Announcements/announcement_id/Comments/commend_id)' --> announcement_id: announcement_id, commend_id: commend_id, reply_id: null
For string 'Announcements/announcement_id/Comments/comment_id/Replies/reply_id)' --> announcement_id: announcement_id, commend_id: comment_id, reply_id: reply_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Your order of pathParams are predifined, so use split and parse the array.

```
 String s = "Announcements/announcement_id/Comments/comment_id/Replies/reply_id)";
 String [] pathParams = s.split("/");
```

Comment: Thanks this is what exactly I need.

Answer (score 0):

The following method is for more paths

```
String s = "Announcements/announcement_id/Comments/comment_id/Replies/reply_id)";
String[] paths = s.split("/");

if (paths.length % 2 == 0) {
  if (paths.length == 2) {
    System.out.println(paths[1]);
  } else {
    int lastPos = paths.length - 1;
    int beforeLastPos = lastPos - 2;
    System.out.println(paths[beforeLastPos] + " " + paths[lastPos]);
  }
}
```